# Magento APC User Cached Misses

Tags: cache

I'm using APC for my online store, and while the APC file cache is working properly, the user cached entries are very low.

[image: apc user cached vars]

Here are my settings:

[image: apc configuration]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What do you use APC for? Do you use it as a Magento cache backend? or just as opcode cache?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about xdebug

Answer (score 2):

You probably do not need to worry, as the system and user caches in APC are different things. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1965369/1429647